# How to add a 'second elbow' to an 'elbow arrow connector' in Powerpoint 2007?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I'm trying to put together a relatively complex flow-chart thing -as part of a University assignment (health-related, and gosh, does my university love all things Microsoft Office...).

Because of the way the chart progresses I have to connect two objects with a 'double elbow' version of the 'elbow arrow connector.' I accept that perhaps this complexity means I should redesign the chart, but I've tried and failed to simplify things already.

If you'll pardon my ASCII art, this is what I have:

```
+----------------+
| 1              |
|                |
+-------+--------+
        |
        |
+-------+--------+      /\
|2      +--------|-----/ 3\
+----------------+     \  /
                        \/
```

Shape 1 should connect to shape 3, currently the line doing so passes behind shape 2.

The diagram below shows what I'd prefer, and, frankly, what I *need* to happen.

```
+----------------+
| 1              |
|                |
+-------+--------+
        |
        +-----------+
+----------------+  |   /\
|2               |  +--/ 3\
+----------------+     \  /
                        \/
```

Having explored the various right-click options I'm either being blind and not seeing it, or...well, I'm hoping it's just me being blind and/or stupid, frankly.

If anyone has any suggestions they'd be gratefully received. I'm working with WinXP and Office 2007 (at the university, I run on Ubuntu at home, which possibly explains why I'm missing something potentially simple)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I played around and found a possible solution for you. Just rotate the Decision shape 90 degrees clockwise. Then the elbow connector will be as you need. Screenies:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ha! I knew there was something simple I was over-looking...thanks! +1, and accepted. =)

Comment: Nice to help. You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I needed exactly what is described in the question, i.e., the line was required to connect shape 3 coming from the left.

[image]

**Step 1**: connecting the line to the top side will create two elbows. 
**Step 2**: drag the upper "yellow point" down to the desired position.
**Step 3**: use `Drawing tools -> Format -> Size` to resize until the line touchest the lowest border

From now on, do NOT move the edges of the line, because the elbows will be reset. Instead, move the whole line or use the resize function.

In general, with this workaround, you can get up to **three** elbows (by connecting top of one shape to bottom of another), and after that move the line where needed.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a faster way that can create any number of elbows with any orientation you want .. You can create a free form of the shape you want. Then create an arrow. Then copy the format of the arrow to the free form. Like this picture shows[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEMLC.png)

It worked with word and Power Point and I think it might work for all office apps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).